# Let $f$ be a periodic holomorphic function in some neighborhood of $\infty$ , prove $f$ is a constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have trouble understanding the part about in some neighborhood of $\infty$.

To my understanding, $f(z) = f(z+n)$ for some large enough $z$. If so, then naively I want to say that by taking a closed bounded neighborhood of $\infty$, the due to the holomorphicity, $f$ has to attain its maximum on the boundary. Say it is $f(z*)$, then $z*+n$, will be also in the neighborhood, and by maximum modulus principle, $f$ must be constant. 
However, I don’t believe that’s how neighborhood of $\infty$ works.

To prove $f$ is constant, I only know $0$ derivative or maximum modulus principle. Can anyone correct me on my misconception about $\infty$ neighborhood, and point me a strategy on solving this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you perhaps missing an assumption that $f$ is entire? Because otherwise $1/z$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $\infty$.

Comment: I’m sorry, I did miss something. f is not entire but it is periodic.

Comment: Let me give you a hint: from those conditions, it follows that $f$ *is* entire.

Comment: I don’t understant why f being periodic and holomorphic for large enough |z| implies f is entire. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Actually the claim is **not true** as $f(z) = e^z$ satisfies the hypotheses (it is entire and $f(z+2\pi i) = f(z)$) and is not constant.

Below we only prove that $f$ may be considered entire.

---

Fix $R>0$ and $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| > R\}$ a neighborhood of $\infty$ where $f$ is defined. Being periodic means that there exist some complex number $\tau$ such that $f(z+\tau) = f(z)$ if $|z|>R$ and $|z+\tau|>R$.

Now let $w\in \mathbb{C}$. There exists a natural $n$ such that $|w+n\tau|>R$. Hence we define a function $g\colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ by $g(w)= f(w+n\tau)$.

It follows that $g$ is well defined by the periodicity of $f$, it extends $f$ tho the whole $\mathbb{C}$ and **$g$ is entire**.

---

To give an affirmative answer we need $f$ to be **doubly-periodic** i.e to have $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ such that $$f(z + \tau_1) = f(z+\tau_2) = f(z)$$
in this case the values of $f$ are determined in the parallelogram with vertices $\{0, \tau_1, \tau_2, \tau_1+\tau_2\}$. In particular $f$ is bounded.

Comment: So the being holomorphic implies f being finite on any compact set, then the periodicity takes the finiteness to infinite. Therefore f is bounded. Then by extending f to the entire complex plane, we obtain an bounded entire function. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I see, but if we have that f is holomorphic at the point infinity, then we can have the boundedness. Otherwise, f has to be at least doubly-periodic.